# iPad iPhone scale background images

Tags: iphone, mobile, ipad, safari, webkit

Just wondering if anyone else has experienced the iPad/iPhone scaling their background images down to fit the view port.

In my case, I'm swapping out background images via javascript, and the new background images are super wide to fit large displays. However, the iPad is scaling down the background images that are added to the DOM via javascript. I solved this by using "-webkit-background-size" set to the size that the image should be, but this causes the background image to be stretched and pixelated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This worked for on iPad:

```
-webkit-background-size: length_x length_y;
```

Comment: Yes, this is a better answer to the question. You can also use % for length and height.

Comment: While this "works", the image looks shitty afterwards. Because iOS first scales the picture 50% down, and then upscales the 50% downscaled version. Result is really crappy looking picture. Aww I hate these non-standard behaviors.

Comment: I can confirm this solution works for an first gen iPod Touch running iOS 3. Newer versions of iOS (not sure if starting from 4, definitely from 5) support the regular background-size.

Answer (score 12):

The iphoneOS scales every picture with above 2 million pixels (width*height) 50% down.
I managed it with spliting the background into two pictures.

Comment: Interesting, I wound up using a smaller version of the same image for iPad users, I suppose since it was less than 2 million pixels- I no longer had the problem.

Comment: Interesting, I can confirm this behavior too. Any idea where to get some official documentation on this?

Comment: just found some docu here:
http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is add this meta tag within the  of your pages to prevent the background image from being scaled.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: The viewport meta tag only influences the page initial scale and its ranges. When the iPad is serving an image that is larger than 2M in pixels, it will scale to 50% regardless of the viewport setting.

Comment: I've discovered initial-scale=1.0 is really important for the correct display of background images.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if you export your image as a 32 bit png (I use Fireworks to do so), and use that png in your background instead of a jpg file, IOS won't scale the image. Works like a charm, and the size is about the same as a jpg with 100% quality (slightly smaller actually)

Also, aditionally for a better experience in ipad / iphone, you should:

a) set a min with do the body tag (mine is usually 980px)

```
body {
    min-width: 980px;
}
```

b) set the same width to the viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980px">
```

Users should now be able to:
- see the design as you have created it
- zoom the content (wich they couldn't if you used  "initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" on the viewport meta tag)
- change the device landscape to portrait and vice versa with no issues