# iPad background image resizing

Tags: css, ipad

I have a rather large image and when I view it on an iPad it scales really small, I did a little research and discovered that I needed to add in a background size which I have done but the image looks all fuzzy and not as sharp as I'd liked. I have tried splitting the image up but it's not working as my image is a load of people's pictures and I have already set up the background positions. Is there anyway I can make the image appear clearer than what it is? Thanks in advance.

The image is 11025px x 348px.

```
.box .image {
    background:url('../images/images.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
    background-size:11025px 348px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details. What's the image resolution? "Rather large" does not really help. How do you load it and how does your css look like? Maybe you simply broke the image size limit in which case iOS halves image resolution to save memory.

Comment: Googling `iPad background image resizing` gives me plenty of good results, many of them on Stack Overflow

Comment: possible duplicate of [A way to correct background scaling in iPad's Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966803/a-way-to-correct-background-scaling-in-ipads-safari)

Answer (score 2):

There is your problem right there: [iOS Resource Limits](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15)

Taken from the guide:

> Because of the memory available on iOS, there are limits on the number of resources it can process:
>
> - The maximum size for decoded GIF, PNG, and TIFF images is 3 megapixels for devices with less than 256 MB RAM and 5 megapixels for devices with greater or equal than 256 MB RAM.
>   That is, ensure that width * height ≤ 3 * 1024 * 1024 for devices with less than 256 MB RAM. Note that the decoded size is far larger than the encoded size of an image.
> - The maximum decoded image size for JPEG is 32 megapixels using subsampling.
>   JPEG images can be up to 32 megapixels due to subsampling, which allows JPEG images to decode to a size that has one sixteenth the number of pixels. JPEG images larger than 2 megapixels are subsampled—that is, decoded to a reduced size. JPEG subsampling allows the user to view images from the latest digital cameras.

The background size won't help you much when the system scales your image back to 5512 x 174 pixels.

Comment: I have tried a JPEG background image of 2000x4000 which is way bigger than 2 megapixels and it worked. However, 2000x4500 resulted in a resized background. So this information may be obsolete.

Comment: What you describe results in 8 respective 9 megapixels. This seems like an odd boundary. And as stated, using subsampling you can use up to 32 megapixels. Maybe your images ware encoded differently? However, without knowing which device and OS you tested on I can not validate you claims. Usually apple keeps it's resources up to date in this regard.